# Chrome and Firefox Crash When Bringing Up Windows Explorer

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, windows-explorer, crash

I am having a weird issue lately on my laptop.  I am running Windows 7 and I have IE v10, Chrome v36, and Firefox v31. All my browsers are up to date and all Windows Updates are installed.  The issue I am seeing is that IE crashes seconds after I open it (before it even has time to load a page) and Chrome & Firefox crash whenever it brings up Windows Explorer (uploading files or Save As).  For Chrome and Firefox, even if you just hit control + s to save, it immediately crashes.

I have tried booting into safe mood and the issues still occur.  I have also tried doing a system restore to a week ago before the issues started but that is failing each time I try that too (tried in safe mood as well).  I have tried disabling all plugins with no luck as well.  I have done alot of google searching with no luck.  I also tried doing everything on this [page](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/google-chrome-crashing-freezing-windows-computer) to resolve it.

At this point, I think it is a windows issue since it happens with their IE product and only happens in Chrome/Firefox whenever Windows Explorer is needed.  Does anyone have any further suggestions for me to try?

**EDIT**

I will also add that I have Symantec Antivirus and Malwarebytes on the laptop and the scans from each haven't resolved the issues either.

Comment: I will be honest.  Based on the behavior you described.  It sounds like you have serious system intregity issues.  Have you used the SFC tool to verify if any corruption is detected?

Comment: "booting into safe mood" hehehe, that seems somehow more appropriate. :D

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, I have used the SFC tool to try and fix any issues that maybe occurring and that also didn't resolve it.

Comment: Did it find problems and report it couldn't repair them or did it find no problems, or did it find problems and was able to repair them?  You can always attempt to update IE11.  You could also choose to uninstall IE10.  You can also attempt a system repair longer then a week ago.

Comment: @Ramhound I must have overlooked it the first time, I just did a sfc/scannow and it shows that it found corrupt files but was unable to fix some of them.  I went through the process to read the CBS.log file created and it says msls31.dll couldn't be repaired.

Comment: Have you tried `sfc /SCANNOW /OFFBOOTDIR=c:\ /OFFWINDIR=c:\windows` while in the Windows Recovery Environment?

Comment: The only other solution I can think of would require you do an "in-place" upgrade to Windows 7 SP1.  This would likely solve your problems but keep your installed programs and personal files.